# LTSPICE AC analysis problem

Tags: ac, analysis

AC analysis dont work for second circuit. If i delete some transistors from 1-st circuit, it starts to work for second circuit.[image]

Comment: Which Transistors do you delete? For clarification, is the circuit on the left the “1-st circuit” and the circuit on the right is the second? The two circuits appear to have the same number of transistors

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? The circuits look identical, one should do the same as the other. Also when you do a plot label the nodes with some meaningful name, we can't tell which nodes are n003 and n004 from looking at it.

Comment: Yes 1st circuit left, second right. Two circuit are absolutely identical. n003 and n004 are identical points (after 10Meg resistors) from 1st and 2nd circuits. Second circuit AC analysis dont work at all.

Comment: If I delete first circuit, or even only two button transistors, second circuit starts to work.

Comment: Well. It starts to work after reinstall.

Comment: @AraAra LTspice can be a bit glitchy at times. On one of my computers it won't show plots when I do a STEP command unless I click the point to plot and re-run it, then it shows but if I do anything that changes the plot window like zooming or trying to plot another node the traces disappear. Sometimes it will act up and you just have to restart it or reload your file.